# Superclass for UITableViewController and UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

Is any ViewController which is super class for UITableViewController and UIViewController ? Because I need it for not copy my business logic.

Comment: Please specify what you are trying to do.

Comment: `UITableViewController` is just a `UIViewController` with the `UITableViewDateSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` implemented. So what you could do is implement these in a custum base viewcontroller and you will not need the `UITableViewController` at all. Especially if you create custom classes as you data source for `UITableViewDateSource`.

Answer (score 2):

As the other commenter said, UITableViewController is a fairly thin API on top of a UIViewController. You might be able to start from UIViewController and add the required logic to manage your table view to your custom class. However, there are some things that UITableViewController supports, like static table views and cell prototypes, that would be difficult or impossible to support if you did not use a UITableViewController.

Another alternative would be to create a category of UIViewController and add your extra methods to the category. Category methods are available to the class they are added to and all subclasses, almost as if you added the methods to the base class.

There are a couple of restrictions to category methods however.

- You can't override methods from the base class, only add new methods.
- You can't add instance variables in a category.

Comment: And be sure to prefix category method names if you're adding methods to a class from a third-party framework so that they don't accidentally collide with existing method names (especially for private methods) now or in the future.

Answer (score 2):

i'm currently attempting to accomplish the same (create a superclass to place custom logic for all my VCs to execute). in my particular scenario, i want to track screen views using google analytics' API, which should be called in `viewWillAppear`. this would require me to place whatever code is required within that method for every view controller.

but i found this gem: [method sizzling](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/). thanks to mr. mattt thompson for that!

if you read closely, you will find that you will be able to create a category in which you have the power to replace the existing implementation of a given selector.

however as pointed out by @duncan d, if you seek to just extend behavior, you can simply create a regular category.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MVC` pattern in your application and you can create a `Model` for storing your business logic and it can communicate with your view through `ViewController` object.

Answer (score 0):

NSObject is a father of most of the classes .. you need to provide datasource and delegate class to implement the table view controller ..

Answer (score -1):

Create an **NSObject class** and write all your **Business Logic** there and make it as **Singletone** and call this class where ever you want